# NodeJS + Mongoose: Application hang (?) after tried add a data to database

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I just learned about NodeJS, ExpressJS & Mongoose. and I tried to create a `RESTful API` with it. Here are the files that I already created:

./Server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import routes from './routes';
import connectDB from './database/connect';

const app = express();
const JWT_SECRET = 'api';

app.use(connectDB);
app.set('secretKey', JWT_SECRET);
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(routes);

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Application is running');
});
```

./database/Connect.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import chalk from 'chalk';
import dbConfig from '../config/database';

const connected = chalk.bold.cyan;
const error = chalk.bold.yellow;
const disconnected = chalk.bold.red;
const termination = chalk.bold.magenta;

const URI = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/data_test';
const Options = { 
    useNewUrlParser: true,
};

export default () => {
    mongoose.connect(URI, Options);
    const connection = mongoose.connection;

    connection.on('connected', () => {
        console.log(connected(`Database connection is open to ${URI}`));
    });
    connection.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log(error(`An error has been occured: ${err}`));
    });
    connection.on('disconnected', () => {
        console.log(disconnected('Database connection is disconnected'));
    });
    process.on('SIGINT', () => {
        connection.close(() => {
            console.log(termination('Database connection is disconnected due to application termination'));
            process.exit(0);
        });
    });
};
```

./app/User.js (model)

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

const saltRounds = 10;

// Define a schema
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
}, {

});

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    this.password = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, saltRounds);
    next();
});

export default mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

./app/controllers/UserController.js

```
import UserModel from '../User';

class UserController
{
    /**
     * Create a new user
     * 
     * @param {*} req 
     * @param {*} res 
     * @param {*} next 
     */
    store(req, res, next)
    {
        UserModel.create({
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password
        }, (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                next(err);
            } else {
                res.status(200).send({
                    status: 'Success',
                    message: 'User added successfully',
                    data: {
                        user: {
                            id: user.id
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}

const Controller = new UserController();
export default Controller;
```

./routes/index.js

```
import express from 'express';
import UserRoutes from './user';

const app = express();

app.use('/user', UserRoutes);

app.all('*', (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).send({msg: 'page not found'});
});

export default app;
```

./routes/user.js

```
'use strict';

import express from 'express';
import UserController from '../app/controllers/UserController';

const Router = express.Router();

Router.post('/register', UserController.store);

export default Router;
```

That's all the files that I already created, but the problem I got is when I tried to add a new user it's stuck on the loading and the new user I just added it doesn't goes to database as well.

[image]

Here's the log file, (there are no errors at all so I don't know where is the problem).

Please help, I already read [Mongoose Documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html) but still don't know where is the problem.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `connectDB` which you've exported from `database/Connect.js` is not a valid `express middleware`. With express you've to call `next` in the middleware to tell express to move on to the next middleware otherwise express will wait till you call it.

```
// You've mounted it like middleware
app.use(connectDB);

// but next is not a param here and you've not invoked.
export default () => {
  ...
  // rest of the code
}
```

Two ways you can fix:

Dont' mount it as middleware:

```
connectDB()
```

Or make it a *proper* middleware and call `next`:

```
export default (req, res, next) => {
  ...
  // rest of the code
  // at the end
  next() // <-- important
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it's working after I don't mount it as middleware :D, but when I tried to call it as a middleware, why does it's returns `next is not a function` at `connect.js`? I already following your 2nd answer

Comment: ah nevermind, I forgot to remove the `()` bracket from `connectDB` in the `server.js` when calling it as a middleware. Thanks!